# how to allow user to order columns with wxListCtrl in report mode

Tags: wxwidgets, report

with wxListCtrl, how to allow the user to rearrange the column order at runtime ?
just like in windows.

Tnx,
Vertilka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wxListCtrl has quite a limited set of features.  I do not know whether or not it includes this.  However, if you want to get fancy, switch to using wxGrid, which has this and almost every other feature you could imagine, and is also part of the wxWidgets toolset.